# Why I get null error for my object in view model when I try to modify it with command in MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I have a weird situation which I can't figure it out. 
I'm using MVVM to build a program which uses OAPI from a commercial software.
I created a public field of that API inside my view-model. then I created two method and use commands to bind them to two buttons in my UI.
one of the methods is responsible for connecting to the API and the other one is responsible for retrieving data from the commercial software.
the first method does the job and makes the connection to software. but when I call the second command to retrieve data I get an error which says your object is null.
when I use the fist command one more time it says that we are already connected which means my object is not null. but I still get error in the second method. all methods are public and defined inside view-model.

both methods are being called by commands

I cant see where I'm making a mistake.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me.
best regards

In view-model I defined these properties which are required by OAPI

```
//dimension the ETABS Object as cOAPI type
    public ETABSv1.cOAPI myETABSObject { get; set; }
    public ETABS2016.cOAPI myETABSObject16 { get; set; }
    public ETABSv1.cSapModel mySapModel { get; set; }
    public ETABS2016.cSapModel mySapModel16 { get; set; }
```

this is my Cammand class:

```
internal class GetStoryDataFromEtabsCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
    public GetStoryDataFromEtabsCommand(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.GetStoryDataFromEtabs();
    }
}
```

there is another command exactly like above but calls ConnectToEtabs() method

this is my ConnectToEtabs() method:

```
public void ConnectToEtabs()
{
    //get the active ETABS object
    myETABSObject16 = 
    (ETABS2016.cOAPI) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject 
    ("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject");
    //Get a reference to cSapModel to access all API classes and functions
    mySapModel16 = myETABSObject16.SapModel;
}
```

this is my GetStoryDataFromEtabs() method:

```
public void GetStoryDataFromEtabs()
{
   double BaseElev = 0;
   string[] notneededst = null;
   int NumOfStory = 0;
   double[] storyElev = null;
   double[] notneededd = null;
   Boolean[] notneededbool = null;
   int[] notneededint = null;
   ret = mySapModel16.Story.GetStories(ref NumOfStory, ref notneededst, ref 
         storyElev, ref notneededd, ref notneededbool, ref notneededst, ref 
         notneededbool, ref notneededd);
   earthQuake.NumberOfStory = NumOfStory;
   earthQuake.BuildingHeight = Math.Round((storyElev[NumOfStory] - 
   storyElev[0]), 2);
}
```

in GetStoryDataFromEtabs() method mySapModel16 is null.
one other thing: each command is being used by different buttons from different user controls.

Comment: "*I cant see where I'm making a mistake*" - we also. Please show us the relevent parts of your code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. Crystal balls and clairvoyants are in short supply, but at a guess I'd say that each command triggers a Task to perform your processing and the second one doesn't have a valid reference to an instance of something.

Comment: hello dear @Clemens ,thank you for your reply. you're right. I edited my question to include my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line may be where your error is thrown, can you confirm this?

```
ret = mySapModel16.Story.GetStories(ref NumOfStory, ref notneededst, ref 
         storyElev, ref notneededd, ref notneededbool, ref notneededst, ref 
         notneededbool, ref notneededd);
```

My reasoning is two-fold,

1. `ref` types must be initialised before they are passed into
   functions.
2. You are then using one of those reference types later:

`earthQuake.BuildingHeight = Math.Round((storyElev[NumOfStory] - 
   storyElev[0]), 2);`

If your function `mySapModel16.Story.GetStories(…)` initialises the parameters that you pass to it then you should use `out` instead.

On another you should consider having your ViewModel implement the ICommand property that you are Binding to and have it trigger a Task e.g.

```
public ICommand GetStoryDataFromEtabsCommand{get;set;}
public bool IsConnected{get;private set;}
```

and in constructor

`GetStoryDataFromEtabsCommand = new Command(()=>GetStoryDataFromEtabs(), ()=>IsConnected);`

where `IsConnected` is set once you have a connection performed by your connection function.

Then 
`public void GetStoryDataFromEtabs()` becomes `public Task GetStoryDataFromEtabs()`. This will allow you to make the function asynchronous and await the call to `mySapModel16.Story.GetStories(…)` if you find that it takes a long time.

Comment: the way that this commercial software's API works is that, I should first define myEtabsObject16 which is of type of EtabsObject16 which is referenced in visual studio. it's a COM object. then there is sapModel which I have to make an instance of it. that would be mySapModel.
the problem is user should be able to connect to Etabs software when he wants. that's fine.
it works.
user also should be able to get data whenever he wants. so it should be another command. and it's being called from another usercontrol. but when he does myEtabsObject is null !!! which first command initiated it. why

Comment: so it doesn't get to the point to run this line:
ret = mySapModel16. ....
because mySapModel16 is null.

Comment: I see that your ViewModel is a property of your Command class rather than the other way around. Is it possible that the two Command instatnces that you have are not referencing the same instance of ViewModel?